# Resize content of iframe/object tag loaded from other domain

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

I have a script which loads links to content and shows it in iframe or object tag. When content located on same server as script - I can access and resize it with

`iFrameObject.contentDocument().getElementsByTag().width = ...;`

But when content is on other server I met cross-domain restrictions.
Please give me an advice is (and how) this can be solved without using additional frameworks, just with `HTML` and `Javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read or write properties of iframes loaded from other domains. That's all there is to it.

Some resources:

- [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)
- [google code](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2)

Comment: if you have access to the iframe script you can set its `document.domain` to match the parent.